# error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope using std::cout

Tags: c++

I downloaded a c++ project and was able to compile it using a makefile generated by cmake.

However when I try to add my own series of .h files in one of the .hh files of the project I start to get a million of errors, one of them being:

> error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
>    using std::cout;

When the .h file that contains 
`using std::cout` is used elsewhere it works, but when added to this project it gives this error.

What can be the problem?

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
class TextManager : public FileManager {
    public:
        TextManager (const char * filename);
        void scanFile (Image &image, Scene &scene);
        void scanObjectModel (Image &image, Scene &scene);
        void getImageData (Image &image);
        void getMaterialData (Scene &scene);
        void getLightData (Scene &scene);
        void getSphereData (Scene &scene);
        void getPlaneData (Scene &scene);
        void getTriangleData (Scene &scene);
        int getLineValue (int size);
        void getLineValue2 (float (&lineNumbers) [10], Scene &scene, int &lineNumbersIndex);
        void getVerticesValues (int initPos, Scene &scene);  
        private:
   std::string line;
   float fractionaryTenPowers [6];
};
```

Problem solved. Was the lack of a bracket to close the declaration of one of the classes that was causing it.

Comment: Please post an MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is that the first error? Or is some other error the real error and the poor, confused compiler no longer understands the code by the time it gets to that line.

Comment: Yes, it is the first error. How can I do MCVE of so much code, good part of not made by me ?

Comment: Stylistic comment: `using` in `.h` files is considered bad style in a lot of places.

Answer (score 16):

The error means you've done this:

```
struct Foo {
  using std::cout;
  ...
};
```

That's not valid C++, in a class body you can only add a using-declaration for members of base classes, not arbitrary names.

You can only add `using std::cout` at namespace scope or inside a function body.

Comment: But the `using std::cout` it is just before class declaration. Should I remove it and put it inside every member function that needs it?

Comment: _"But the using std::cout it is just before class declaration."_ No it isn't, or you wouldn't get that error. Either put it in every function, or just write `std::cout` and don't bother with the using-declaration.

Comment: Jonathan How can that be possible. I just edited my first message with the code. You can see that the class declaration follows the using stuff

Comment: Are you sure TextManager isn't a nested class defined inside another class?  The compiler output suggests it is.

Comment: Pretty sure it it isn't

Comment: While this answer is technically debatable accurate, it (and the followup discussion) is a classic example of presuming way too much based on the literal meaning of the compiler error.  E.g. if a compiler tells you "expected semicolon here", you don't just add a semicolon there and go on your merry way.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in the class as long as you put it under the `public` or `private` sections.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace CoolNamespace
{
  struct AnotherReallyLongClassName
  {
    int a = 75;
  };

  struct SomeReallyLongClassName
  {
    int a = 42;
  };
} // namespace CoolNamespace

class Widget
{

  // You can't do this though!
  // using ShorterName = CoolNamespace::SomeReallyLongClassName;

  public:

    // You can use a using statement inside of a class!
    using ShorterName = CoolNamespace::SomeReallyLongClassName;
    ShorterName foo;

    int get_another_name()
    {
      return bar.a;
    }

  private:
    // You can do it here also!
    using AnotherName = CoolNamespace::AnotherReallyLongClassName;
    AnotherName bar;
};

int main()
{
  Widget widget;
  std::cout << widget.foo.a << std::endl;

  // Also, if you can reference public using statements from the class definition.
  Widget::ShorterName thing;
  std::cout << thing.a << std::endl;

  // But you can't do this because it's private.
  // Widget::AnotherName name;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi. I am afraid you're missing the point. What you talk about is [type alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias), while what the original poster asks about is [using-declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration). They both use `using` but are different. For example, in `class Widget` in your example, even if you put `using std::cout;` under `public:`, you will *still* get an **error** saying `using-declaration for non-member at class scope`.

Answer (score -2):

Indeed, check if you have one open bracket in one of the member functions in the class declaration.

I did this in .h file;

```
class foo{
    void cat();
    void bar{
    void dog();
}

in .cc file I defined the member functions
void foo::cat(){
    std::cout<<"This is cat"<<std::endl;
}

void foo::bar(){
    std::cout<<"hello"<<std::endl;
}

void foo::dog(){
    std::cout<<"meow"<<std::endl;
}
```

But notice I used { instead of; for member function bar in .h file. That's causing the error. (At least for me).